# CSS3 background-image with bundled sprite image based on images with different original Image Size

Tags: css, background-image, css-sprites

Hello I am currently writing a sprite generator based on CSS 3 and my question is : What is the best practice to show CSS3 background-images with a bundled sprite image based on images with different original Image Size concatenated vertical?

I have tried this here at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s__a/xcZ4j/),

```
.gui-background-brand-nodejs-64, .gui-background-brand-grayscale-nodejs-32{
    background-image: url("http://www.shareimages.com/images/pics/0/0/3/65385-rJWWm5Wfk6ainac-sprite.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.gui-background-brand-nodejs-64{
    width: 238px;
    height: 64px;
    background-position:0 0px;
}

.gui-background-brand-grayscale-nodejs-32{
    width: 119px;
    height: 32px;
    background-position:0 -32px;
}
```

but this technique does only work if all images have the same image size. So in example the second image should have 32px height.
I have worked out compromise solutions at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s__a/xcZ4j/)

*1. via extra HTML markup*, 
but I think it is ugly and I m wondering if there is not a full CSS integration possbile to make css background-image realy usable.

*2. via calculation*

```
.gui-background-brand-grayscale-nodejs-32 {
width: 119px;
height: 32px;
background-size: 238px;
background-position: 0 -64px;
}
```

currently I calculating factors

```
X = (longest image width / current image width)
Y = sum(previous original image HEIGHTs)

background-size: {current image WIDTH*X}px;
background-position: 0 -{Y}px;
```

I wish the css could be defined with the width and height values ​​of the original images because factor X can result in a decimal value. Not easy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok . So far nobody answered so i decided to choose answer 2. Via calculation!
I ve created an Image processing service for web development which handles all the stuff automaticaly at https://github.com/s-a/scream-js if somebody is interested.